# How to make an object move in p5.js in a given time?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Suppose I have a canvas that is 1200px. How do I get an object to move from the starting point (100px) to its endpoint (1000px) within a given time (eg. 10 seconds)? In such a way that it takes the object exactly 10 seconds to traverse from starting point to endpoint.

My code looks like this so far:

```
    function setup()
{
    createCanvas(img.width, img.height);

    //Initialize x with the start value
    x = startX;
}

function draw()
{
    image(img, 0, 0);

    x = min(endX, x);
    x+=2;

    //stop the object if it's near enough to endx and endy
    if (abs(endX - x) < 30)
    {
        x = endX;
    }

    y = 114;

    //stop the object if it goes off of the screen
    x = min(x, 1200);
    x = max(x, 0);

    var spotlightSize = 114;

    blendMode(BLEND);
    background(10);
    image(spotlight_image, x-spotlightSize/2, y-spotlightSize/2, spotlightSize, spotlightSize);
    blendMode(DARKEST);
    image(img, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the frame rate was perfect and constant, you could simply divide the distance to travel by the amount of frames in the time that it takes. That result would be how far you need to travel in each frame. The frame rate is not perfect or constant, but we will write a program assuming a perfect frame rate because it will help us later.

What you need to do is:

1. Find how many frames will pass in the time you want to move - multiply the time to move by the frames per second
2. Find the displacement from the start to the end - subtract the start from the end
3. Divide the displacement by the amount of frames that will pass
4. Move that far each frame until you are close enough to the end

An example implementation: (you used only x-position but I used vectors as they will probably be useful to someone in the future)

```js
new p5();

const fps = 60; // frames per second

const startPos = createVector(100, 50);
var position = startPos.copy();
const endPos = createVector(600, 450);
const stopAtDist = 30; // stop if it's this far from the end point in any direction
const distToTravel = p5.Vector.sub(endPos, startPos);

const moveDurationS = 10; // Move duration in seconds
const moveDurationFrames = moveDurationS / (1 / fps); // How many frames will it take to move the distance
const distToMovePerFrame = p5.Vector.div(distToTravel, moveDurationFrames); // How far to move each frame

var currentlyMoving = true;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(800, 500);
    frameRate(fps);
}

function draw() {
    background(0);

    // Draw the start pos
    stroke('yellow');
    strokeWeight(10);
    point(startPos.x, startPos.y);

    // Draw the end pos
    stroke('green');
    point(endPos.x, endPos.y);

    // Draw the current position
    stroke('red');
    point(position.x, position.y);

    // If it's currently moving, then move
    if (currentlyMoving) {
        position.add(distToMovePerFrame);
    }
    // If it is close enough to the end, then stop
    if (abs(dist(position.x, position.y, endPos.x, endPos.y)) < stopAtDist) {
        currentlyMoving = false;
    }
}
```

The frame rate is not constant, though. Fortunately, p5 has a function that tells us how many milliseconds have passed in the last frame. So what we do is:

1. Find how many milliseconds pass in the time you want to move - multiply the seconds you want it to move for by 1000
2. Find out how far it will move per millisecond - divide the start/end displacement by the amount of milliseconds that will pass
3. Each frame, move the distance per millisecond multiplied by how many milliseconds have gone past in that frame.

Here's that translated into code:

```js
new p5();

const fps = 60; // frames per second

const startPos = createVector(100, 50);
var position = startPos.copy();
const endPos = createVector(600, 450);
const stopAtDist = 30; // stop if it's this far from the end point in any direction
const distToTravel = p5.Vector.sub(endPos, startPos);

const moveDurationS = 10;
const moveDurationMs = moveDurationS * 1000;
const distToMovePerMs = p5.Vector.div(distToTravel, moveDurationMs);

var currentlyMoving = true;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(800, 500);
    frameRate(fps);
}

function draw() {
    background(0);

    // Draw the start pos
    stroke('yellow');
    strokeWeight(10);
    point(startPos.x, startPos.y);

    // Draw the end pos
    stroke('green');
    point(endPos.x, endPos.y);

    // Draw the current position
    stroke('red');
    point(position.x, position.y);

    // If it's currently moving, then move
    if (currentlyMoving) {
        var thisFrameMovement = p5.Vector.mult(distToMovePerMs, deltaTime);
        position.add(thisFrameMovement);
    }
    // If it is close enough to the end, then stop
    if (abs(dist(position.x, position.y, endPos.x, endPos.y)) < stopAtDist) {
        currentlyMoving = false;
    }
}
```

I tested the above code and it was pretty accurate - it averaged 0.75% off. I hope that this is what you're looking for in your answer!